# What is the idiomatic way to handle nil and error in Golang?

Tags: go, error-handling

I have 2 go functions:

```
func sampleFunction () {
    u, err := findDog(1)
    if err != nil {
        // We couldn't find the dog, print a message.
        fmt.Println(err)
        // Custom error types.
        if _, ok := err.(*dneError); ok {
            fmt.Println("Custom dog dne error for the end-user here.")
        }
    } else {
        // Do something with u.
        u.doSomething() // Is this idiomatic in Go?
                        // Should we explicility check for u != nil?
                        // Or does the if check above need to return?
                        // (even if I would like the function to be longer)

    }
}

// findDog returns a dog with a given ID. If not found, returns an error.
func findDog(id int) (*models.Dog, error) {
    found, err := models.FindDog(id)
    // Is this return scheme/flow too brittle?
    if err != nil {
        return nil, &dneError{fmt.Sprintf("Dog %d does not exist in the" +
            "database: %s", id, err.Error())}
    }
    return found, nil
}
```

I just want to make sure I'm handling errors and nils correctly, so my 2 main questions are:

1. In findDog, am I returning nil appropriately in both cases?
2. In sampleFunction, is it idiomatic to not explicitly check u != nil, or am I just doing this completely incorrectly?

My goal is to properly show errors/problems to the programmers when they need it, and show errors/problems to the users when they need it, while also adhering to idiomatic standards. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal opinion you are handling it very well, Just a recommendation as I don't know what `models.FindDog(id)` does I would double check `found` and if this is `nil` return error, summarizing `if err != nil  || found == nil {`

*Note: doing this `return err.Error()` could fail*

Comment: Thank you, that's excellent advice. Perhaps I can have 2 separate if cases so err.Error() does not fail. Or just nest another if err != nil. I'll think about it, thank you!

Comment: Wait, how is it possible for `err.Error()` to fail? An `error` is an interface which guarantees that `func Error() string` exists.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear in the example if `models.FindDog(id) return err = nil` the code would says `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` since the err is nil

Comment: Oh I see, because you are using `||` (or) in that check.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is idiomatic Go. Because errors are handled up front, an error means something failed and the result is either `nil`, or e.g. perhaps a partially written buffer that isn't of any use.

P.S. I also have a suggestion that would make things more idiomatic. The idiom goes something like "Indent error blocks, not code". You specifically have an if/else in your `sampleFunction`, yet in most error checking circumstances (not all) you handle it and return, then skip the else and the flow simply continues. Why indent when you don't have to? This has the effect of making even long functions easy to read because the intended flow of the function can be read top-to-bottom and without having to bounce back and forth between if/else blocks. At least in many occasions.

I had a pull request into someone's repository amended because I had an if/else where the if with return was sufficient.

**EDIT**
So my answer was bothering me a little bit, and now I remember why. It's normally idiomatic for a non `nil` `error` return to indicate that the other return value(s) are useless, but there are indeed exceptions. **Be sure to check individual documentation.**

As a concrete example, see [`bytes.Buffer.ReadBytes`](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer.ReadBytes)

> If ReadBytes encounters an error before finding a delimiter, it returns the data read before the error and the error itself (often io.EOF).

Comment: Yes thank you. The "Indent error blocks, not code" idea is why I have the comment that reads "Or does the if check above need to return? (even if I would like the function to be longer)". I mangled that question, but thank you - I will change my code accordingly. A quick follow up: does this imply the need for shorter functions? Since having a long function with an error/return at the top of it seems dangerous. Or is it not dangerous at all? I suppose having long functions in itself is considered bad form anyways.

Comment: @user2801352 Long functions aren't necessarily bad form, but smaller ones are easier to test. I have a production function that follows the idiom I mentioned the whole way through. Over 100 lines all left flush except for `return nil, err` blocks. Admittedly it needs to be refactored and shrunk to be unit tested.

Comment: It also depends on the code though. Often on an error, you simply want to pass it back up to the caller. In cases where you actually handle the error, you'll possibly have if/else blocks and whatever is necessary. A lot of the time that sort of handling is done at the very top level functions, so usually the error is just passed back up the stack by returning

Comment: Although SO discourages these types of comments, I just wanted to say thank you again. I'll be applying your advice in my current project.